# What will be the default filesystem in 16.04?

Tags: filesystem, default, 16.04

Has it been decided what the default filesystem for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS will be? Will it still be ext4?

ext4 is great, but it was already great in ancient Ubuntu 9.10.  Ironically, Wikipedia states

> In 2008, the principal developer of the ext3 and ext4 file systems,
>   Theodore Ts'o, stated that although ext4 has improved features, it is
>   not a major advance, it uses old technology, and is a stop-gap.

It would be nice to get a few new features (ext5?) ... like built-in checksums to help detect and reduce bitrot (perhaps with file-by-file compression).

btrfs seems to continue to be around the corner but suffers from narrow adoption; and although Ubuntu has just announced zfs support, I don't think it is targeted to become the default.

Comment: there is discussion on making zfs as default filesystem

Comment: even though ext4 is the default, you don't have to use it

Comment: a default filesystem is tested a lot more and has a solid future for many years.  a non-default filesystem may run into unusual problems (e.g., boot, recovery, etc) and may or may not work on other installations.  still, you have a point---unlike osx, we have some choice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there were any plans to change the default filesystem, they would be part of [the blueprints for 16.04](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+specs). As you can see, the list of blueprints is rather threadbare compared to the those of [15.10](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/+specs) or [14.04](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+specs), so I guess things haven't really settled yet. So, if there are plans, they aren't "official" yet.

The last time this was discussed in [`ubuntu-devel`](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-devel) was in [April 2015](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2015-April/015480.html). To quote an Ubuntu kernel dev, [Colin King](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2015-April/015487.html):

> After a lot of thorough testing over the past several months, I still
>   deem btrfs as experimental quality. There are still issues that can't
>   be easily recovered from, so personally, I don't recommended it quite
>   yet for a default filesystem.

So, in conclusion:

#### There are no plans to change the default filesystem.